# How does one define a group with commutative diagrams?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

I am currently working through McLarty's book on Elementary Categories, Elementary Toposes. In Chapter 3, he considers a group as an object in a category with a unit map, a multiplication and an inverse map, defined as 
$$e: 1 \to G, \quad m: G \times G \to G, \quad \_^{-1}: G \to G$$ such that the following diagrams commute:

[image: commutative diagrams]

Here are my questions:

1. I don't quite understand the definition of $e$. It maps the terminal object (which would have to be the subgroup of 1 element) into $G$. Why not define $e: G \to G$ since it takes every element to itself?
2. Why isn't the first diagram two-sided to account for $e \cdot x = x = x \cdot e$?
3. Why are the two maps of the second diagram the same? Since we want to claim that $x\cdot x^{-1} = e = x^{-1} \cdot x$, shouldn't one of the top maps be $\left< \_^{-1}, G\right>$?
4. I'm assuming the map ``$G$" means the unique identity map. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks to me like you're confusing the definition of a group object with that of a (categorified) group.

Comment: I'd say “an object”, not “a category with one object”. Left identity together with left inverses for all elements implies right identity (at least for usual groups). The second diagram has an apparent misprint.

Comment: Ok, that clears up everything. I am considering a category of groups for which the group I am interested is an object. I can assume, then, that the group with one element exists. I also do not need a two-sided diagram for $e$ since I should be able to use the second and third diagram (which makes perfect sense!). And the second diagram has a typo. Thank you!

Comment: I think those diagrams are all around messed up and inconsistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are two typos/inconsistent notations in the diagrams (as you found in your questions 3 and 4).

1. Well, yes, the terminal object plays the role of the 'one-element set' in this abstraction, and a map $1\to X$ plays the role of 'selecting an element' of $X$. The map $e$ wants to select the identity element. 
   You are right that one can also consider the constant homomorphism $G\to G$, but observe that this factors through the terminal object as $G\to 1\overset e\to G$.
2. The question is justified, however the other equation follows from the other conditions. Can you translate the classic proof?

   > $\quad xe=xe=xx^{-1}x=ex=x$
3. I guess, the top right arrow is indeed intended as $\langle \_^{-1},\,\mathrm{Id}_G\rangle$. 
   However, even one of these follows from the rest (it is enough to require a left unit and left invertibility) :

   > Let $e$ be the left identity, $y$ be a left inverse of $x$ and $z$ a left inverse for $y$, then $y$ is also right inverse of $x$ as 
   >   $\quad xy=exy=zy\,xy=zey=zy=e$
4. Indeed, the maps denoted as $G$ wants to mean the identity $\mathrm{Id}_G$.

Comment: Here is the diagrammatic translation of the proof (at least I think) http://s22.postimg.org/3rfnx8uk1/Group_Diagrams.png

Thank you for the response!